# JVM option --XX MaxJavaStackTraceDepth when I decrease any value below 10, It is not working

Tags: java, logging, configuration, stack-trace, jvm-hotspot

I am trying to set the jvm option maxJavaStackTraceDepth. So when I increase the JVM option --XX MaxJavaStackTraceDepth above 10. it is working as expected. But when I decrease any value below 10 so it causes NoClassDefFoundError error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ReusableMessageFactory
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2108)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2015)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1886)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.error(AbstractLogger.java:849)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:130)
```

Ideally it should work below 10 values as well
like -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=5
I am using Java 17

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to set a maxJavaStackTraceDepth of 10 or lower?

Comment: Hi @ThomasKläger I want to control  the stack trace depth

Comment: I understand that. But what is the problem that you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: The problem occurs during execution of `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build()`. You can try to gather more information by setting the log level for the `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder` logger to "DEBUG"

Comment: I tested that setting with one of my applications (that happens to also use log4j2 - the place where your code fails) and I could start my application even with `--XX MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=1`

Comment: Hi @ThomasKläger When Exception is raised then we  print the stack trace. This stack trace  run through multiple level and each level dumps a lot of information. that is why i want to control the stack trace depth

Comment: Yes @ThomasKläger you are right .. In my other application it is working... But some how it is not working with my current application. i am using spring-boot-starter-log4j2:3.1.5

Comment: My application also uses spring-boot-starter-log4j2:3.1.5, but my application works. It must be some other dependency or how you configure your logging. Did you try my suggestion about generating more logging? What output did that produce? You might need to do that additional logging once with a stacktracedepth > 10 (where your application runs) and once with a stacktracedepth of 5 (where your application crashes) to find a hint.

Comment: The exception dumps a lot of information *that helps you find the cause of the issue*. Don't know why you wouldn't want that.

Comment: Hi @Tobb Thanks for the comment , As per requirement we do not want  lot of information dumps.

Comment: Some classes use stack traces, e.g. to identify the caller, which may require a certain minimum depth when delegation is used. Of course, the better option would be to use `StackWalker`, introduced with Java 9, but not all frameworks have been updated. So you end up with a library not supporting this option, but in the end, they haven’t been specified to work with this option.

Comment: Hi @ThomasKläger, I did enable logging as DEBUG. and set stacktracedepth as 5.But i am getting same stack trace

Comment: If anyone has an explanation, much appreciated (does it have anything to do with (maximum-activity-trace-stack default value of 10 ?) https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/23.x/23.9/en/application-monitoring/administer-app-server-agents/app-agent-node-properties-reference/app-agent-node-properties-m#:~:text=maximum-activity-trace-stack,Structures)%20are%20set%20to%2010.

Comment: I don't expect the stacktrace to change, I expect some additional log output of the kind "Building Plugin[name=somePluginName, class=somePluginClass]" that can help to identify the problematic code.

Comment: Regarding the link to appdynamics: do you use appdynamics in your project? If you don't use it that linked setting is irrelevant.

Comment: @ThomasKläger thanks for the reply. No we are not using appdynamics in our project.

Comment: any other alternate way to control the stack trace depth?

Answer (score 0):

I did research on it. I have below observation.

When we decrease jvm option MaxJavaStackTraceDepth below a certain threshold, such as 10, it may not work as expected because it can affect the ability of the JVM to provide meaningful stack traces when exceptions are thrown.

Stack traces are crucial for diagnosing and debugging issues in Java applications, as they provide information about the sequence of method calls leading to an exception or error. When the MaxJavaStackTraceDepth is set too low, the JVM may not capture enough information in the stack trace to understand the context of the problem.

It's generally not recommended to set MaxJavaStackTraceDepth to a very low value, especially below 10.